# Angular ignora *ngFor no select option

Tags: angular, typescript, materialize

Estou tentando fazer um campo do tipo `select` em um formulário no Angular com Materialize, e preenchê-lo dinamicamente, mas, ao chegar na diretiva `*ngFor`, o Angular passa a ignorar o campo:

HTML:

```
    <!-- campo que não funciona -->
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <select formControlName="item_id_dinamic">
        <option [ngValue]="" disabled selected>Escolha o item:</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of itens" [ngValue]="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <!-- campo estático funcionando -->
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <select formControlName="item_id_static">
        <option [ngValue]="" disabled selected>Escolha o banco:</option>
        <option [ngValue]="1">Opção 1</option>
        <option [ngValue]="2">Opção 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

O resultado na apresentação dos campos é esse:

[image: Exemplo com opções estáticas e operacional]

*Uso das opções de forma estática*

[image: Resultado usando opções geradas dinamicamente pela aplicação]

*Gerado dinamicamente pela aplicação*

Meu componente TypeScript está montado dessa forma:

```
export class FormItensComponent implements OnInit {

  itens: Item[] = ITENS; // puxado array de outra parte da aplicação
  itemForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    // usado para inicializar o select com Materialize
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
    this.itemForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      item_id_dinamic: ['', Validators.required],
      item_id_static:  ['', Validators.required]
    });
    /* detalhes de leitura de dados do banco omitidas */
  }
}
```

Exemplo de itens possíveis (JSON):

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Item 1'
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'Item 2'
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'Item 3'
},
{
  id: 4,
  name: 'Outro'
}
```

Comment: não faltou ng-Model? exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048605/angularjs-ng-model-in-a-select

Comment: Já estou usando o formControlName para fazer a parte da integração com o formulário (embora não apareça no código acima), aí o Angular me retorna isso: ```It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
    Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7.```

Comment: coloque todo o exemplo então ...

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com os detalhes da implementação

Comment: Manda um JSON de exemplo também de Itens fazendo favor.

Comment: Atualizado com JSON de exemplo de itens

Comment: Leia: https://www.positronx.io/angular-7-select-dropdown-examples-with-reactive-forms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde amigo, existe grande chance da inicialização do componente estar no local errado o comando:

```
var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
```

deve ser executa após os dados já terem sido carregados no select, se você traz os dados em uma promise ou observable fique atendo a isso.

Comment: Teoria interessante, já tinha, inclusive, pensado nisso. Porém, ao utilizar como solução (inclusive utilizando dados estáticos ao invés de puxar da API), a aplicação continua ignorando a existência dos itens. Abaixo, meu código de inicialização:

Comment: ```ngOnInit() {
    this.itens = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Item 1'
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'Item 2'
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'Item 3'
},
{
  id: 4,
  name: 'Outro'
}];
    // usado para inicializar o select com Materialize
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
    this.itemForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      item_id_dinamic: ['', Validators.required],
      item_id_static:  ['', Validators.required]
    });
    /* detalhes de leitura de dados do banco omitidas */
  }```

Comment: o desenho da tela têm que estar totalmente pronto, os dados carregados e a dom renderizada, você não pode usar o ngOnInit nesse caso, só para efeito de teste coloque essa linha que destaquei dentro de um setTimeout com alguns segundos, e verifique se os dados aparecem

Comment: eu sofri com isso já, e era apenas esse o problema, mesmo com dados estáticos, é necessário estar tudo carregado, eu usei o ngAfterViewChecked eu acho, ou executei o codigo no fim da promise que traz os dados

Comment: sobre o codigo acima que você mostrou com dados estáticos, você não esta considerando que existe um bind a ser feito entre o this.itens e o template através do ngFor, o javascript é single thread então qualquer mudança de ordem compromete o resultado

Comment: consegui, era realmente isso, utilizando um ```setTimeout``` com uma arrow function o select passou a funcionar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Percebi um detalhe no seu código, talvez seja a causa. Você declarou a variável de formulário `itemForm: FormGroup` com o nome `itemForm` e inicializou como `bankAccountForm`. Não sei se são dois formulários diferentes. Subi um ambiente 
para teste assumindo `itemForm` e tudo ocorreu normalmente (antes de alterar o select ficava em branco como no seu exemplo).

Fiz esta alteração no seu código:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.itemForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      item_id_dinamic: ['', Validators.required],
      item_id_static:  ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Link do stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrifss

Comment: Boa tarde. Agradeço por notar os erros de nomeclatura. Estava tão entretido com o problema que nem me toquei quando estava digitando o exemplo. Mas, infelizmente, não era esse o problema.

O problema está, justamente, na interação do HTML padrão com o JavaScript presente no framework `materialize`, que não está sendo executado de maneira correta.

Comment: O `materialize` foi instalado no projeto utilizando os pacotes do `node` `materialize-css` e `@types/materialize-css`, e importando seu JavaScript no componente com o seguinte código: ```import * as M from "materialize-css";```